# Angular subscription is call more than once

Tags: angular, service

I have a subscription to service:

```
login(): void {
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
        return;
    }
    const { email, password } = this.loginForm.value;

    this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: res.errorMessage,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This method is call when form is sumbited

```
<h1 class="mat-display-2 mb-0">Login</h1>

<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
            <label>
                <input matInput formControlName="email" type="email" />
            </label>
            <mat-error *ngIf="controls.email.errors">
                <span *ngIf="controls.email.errors.required">{{ 'auth.EMAIL_REQUIRED' | transloco }}</span>
                <span *ngIf="controls.email.errors.email">{{ 'auth.INVALID_EMAIL' | transloco }}</span>
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>{{ 'auth.PWD' | transloco }}</mat-label>
            <label>
                <input matInput formControlName="password" type="password" />
            </label>
            <mat-error *ngIf="controls.password.invalid">{{ 'auth.PWD_REQUIRED' | transloco }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <p *transloco="let t">
        {{ t('auth.LOGIN_HELP') }}
        <a class="d-inline" routerLink="../signup" *transloco="let t">{{ t('auth.SIGNUP') }}</a>
    </p>

    <div class="text-right m-3">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z8" type="submit" *transloco="let t">
            {{ t('auth.LOGIN') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem comes when i change the language in interface because subscription to auth service is call with previous values of reactive form and for example if previous error was happened it fires again with the new language

¿How can i solve it?

I'm using transloco library for language

Complete login component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {
    loginForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

    get controls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
        return this.loginForm.controls;
    }

    login(): void {
        if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
            return;
        }
        const { email, password } = this.loginForm.value;

        this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: res.errorMessage,
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I found a solution but is kind of weird...

```
login(): void {
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
        return;
    }
    const { email, password } = this.loginForm.value;

    let subs: Subscription;
    subs = this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: res.errorMessage,
            });
        }

        subs.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try this: this.authService.login(email, password).pipe(shareReplay()).subscribe(....) or this.authService.login(email, password).pipe(share()).subscribe(...), if it works I'll put it on the answer : )

Comment: Dont' works, it fires again Swal alert error message when i change language even if i don't sumbit form again

Comment: Have you tried pipe(take(1)) ? :   this.authService.login(email, password).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)

Comment: Okey take(1) works but why?

Comment: because "take" will take the first N number of observable emissions, so you are taking 1 emission and ignoring rest.

Comment: Make sure you test it (login + logout + login again) to be sure it works. Do u mind if  I answer and u vote me the topic ? gracias :P

Comment: Yes i test it and works, thanks (pd: claro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this (there are a lot of operators and use cases around RxJS), but as a valid solution/workaround the problem would get fixed if you just pick up the first emitted observable by using RxJS Operator "take", so you get rid of those repeated subscriptions coming next.

**Example:
On your AuthService call add a take(1):**

```
 this.authService
   .login(email, password)
   .pipe(take(1))
   .subscribe(...)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the take(1) operator should be the better way as if the subscription goes inside the if block, it goes to the other page without unsubscribing. Otherwise you can also make sure the subscription is unsubscribed onDestroy(). take(1) automatically will cover this scenario as it unsubscribes after the first data comes only. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take